# Methods to return a list of values from rpgle procedure

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am looking for method of returning more than one value(like an array) from a subprocedure in `rpgle`.I don't want to use files etc. to store this value.
Can somebody recommend any good method to achieving this?

Comment: Need some more information.  How big a list of values?  What are your returning them too?

Comment: The number of values can vary from 0 to 20.Basically these value will be used to display on screen(i am thinking subfile).

Comment: It's best to edit your question to include any additional information.  That way it's all in one place.

Comment: Are you passing back a simple type or a complex data structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only a maximum of 20 values being passed back...

You could pass the array back directly..

```
   dcl-proc TestProc;
     dcl-pi *n char(20) dim(20) ;
       parm1 char(20);
     end-pi;

     dcl-s myarray char(20) dim(20); 

     return myarray;
   end-proc;
```

Optionally, you could define the proc as returning `DIM(200)` for instance and pass in a value for how many values you actually want.  The compiler will happily truncate the `DIM(200)` into a `DIM(20)` when you do the call.  This would provide a bit more flexibility.  The downside would be performance if you intend to call this 1,000s of times a second.  Returning "large" values has some performance penalties.

Assuming a recent version of the OS, IBM added the RTNPARM keyword to improve the performance of large return values.

```
   dcl-proc MainProc;
   dcl-s arr char(20) dim(20);
     arr = TestProc(%elem(arr));
     dsply arr(1);
   end-proc;

   dcl-proc TestProc;
     dcl-pi *n char(20) dim(200) rtnparm ;
       howmany int(10) value;
     end-pi;

     dcl-s myarray char(20) dim(200);
     dcl-s x int(10);
     for x = 1 TO howmany;
         // load array
         myarray(x) = 'Something';
     endfor;
     return myarray;
   end-proc;
```

Data queue's as David mentioned and Data Area's are other possibilities.

They might make for more accessibility from another language.  But they are a bit hard to use.  Luckily, you could always provide a wrapper the converts the returned array into something else.

Comment: Thanks I have this idea of returning the array but i am liitle bit skeptic that whether it will work if i call the procedure from a different module.I mean the array in procedure is local so would it be not cleared when the procedure end.Pardon me if this is a silly question.

Comment: No, returned values are returned "by value"; you're not returning a pointer to `myarray`.  In other words, behind the scenes the data is copied.  Twice IIRC.  Thus the performance hit for large returned values.

Comment: RTNPARM changes what goes on behind the scenes.  But the end result is the same.  You're still not returning the address for `myarray`.

Answer (score 5):

If the called procedure decides how many elements to return, then if using the return-value mechanism, it would be good to define the return value as a data structure that has the array and the number of values.

**copy file**

```
dcl-c MAX_VALUES_RETURNED 20;
dcl-ds values_t qualified template;
   num int(10);
   arr char(200) dim(MAX_VALUES_RETURNED);
end-ds;
dcl-pr proc likeds(values_t) rtnparm;
 ...
```

**caller**

```
dcl-ds values likeds(values_t);
values = proc(parms);
for i = 1 to values.num;
     ... handle values.arr(i)
```

Comment: For Additional Info, refer to "Support nested output arrays" section in:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-integrated-web-services-server/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a data queue to send a list of values back.

The procedure would send the results to the data queue and return a data queue name (or key for a keyed data queue).

The calling program would then read the data queue (possibly by key, if the queue is pre-existing) and process the entries.

Data queues are fast, easy, and you have the added advantage of being able to use it with other languages ... even if they aren't on the IBM i (java, for example).

Comment: Thanks David!! will certainly try this

Comment: A *DTAQ isn't bad, especially for its simplicity. But I'd probably use either a user index (*USRIDX) or user space (*USRSPC) instead. All entries could be loaded or retrieved to/from a *USRIDX with single operations, and a *USRSPC could simply use a pointer to it to overlay a DS of entries. Actually, I might just allocate memory in the caller for a desired number of entries, then pass the address to the proc along with a parm to tell how many entries should be added.